# How to get particular index number of list items

Tags: python, arraylist, data-science

```
my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'F', 'D', 'C', 'B']

idx = my_list.index('B')
print("index :", idx)
```

In here I used the '.index()' function.

```
for i in my_list:
    print(f"index no. {my_list.index(i)}")
```

I tried to find each index number of the items of the (my_list) list.
But it gave same result for same values. But they located in difference places of the list.

```
if 'B' == my_list[(len(my_list) - 1)]:
    print("True")

if 'B' == my_list[(len(my_list) - 4)]:
    print("True")
```

I need to mention particular values by the index number of their (to do something).
Imagine; I need to set values to nesting with the values of the list.
i.e :

```
my_list_2 = ['A', 'B', '2', 'C', '3', 'D', '4', 'E', 'B', '2', 'F', '6', 'D', 'C', '3', 'B']
              -    ------    ------    ------    -    ------    ------    -    ------    -
```

If I want to nesting values with their Consecutive (number type) items and
the other values need to nest with '*' mark (as default).Because they have no any Consecutive (numeric) values.

so then how I mention each (string) values and (numeric) values in a coding part to nesting them.
In this case as my example I expected result:

--> my_list_2 = [['A', '*'], ['B', '2'], ['C', '3'], ['D', '4'], ['E', '*'], ['B', '2'], ['F', '6'], ['D', '*'], ['C', '3'], ['B', '*']]

This is the coding part which I tried to do this :

```
def_setter = [
    [my_list_2[i], '*'] if my_list_2[i].isalpha() and my_list_2[i + 1].isalpha() else [my_list_2[i], my_list_2[i + 1]]
    for i in range(0, len(my_list_2) - 1)]
```

print("Result : ", def_setter)

But it not gave me the expected result.

Could you please help me to do this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a more pythonic way to reorganize this array, however, with the following function you can loop through the list and append `[letter, value]` if value is a number, append `[letter, '']` if value is a letter.

```
def_setter = []
i = 0
while i < len(my_list_2):
    if i + 1 == len(my_list_2):
        if my_list_2[i].isalpha():
            def_setter.append([my_list_2[i], ''])
            break
    prev, cur = my_list_2[i], my_list_2[i + 1]
    if cur.isalpha():
        def_setter.append([prev, ''])
        i += 1
    else:
        def_setter.append([prev, cur])
        i += 2
print(def_setter)

>>> [['A', ''],
 ['B', '2'],
 ['C', '3'],
 ['D', '4'],
 ['E', ''],
 ['B', '2'],
 ['F', '6'],
 ['D', ''],
 ['C', '3'],
 ['B', '']]
```

Comment: But this is notnot I expected output. I need to get the result as : [['A', ''], ['B', '2'], ['C', '3'], ['D', '4'], ['E', ''], ['B', '2'], ['F', '6'], ['D', ''], ['C', '3'], ['B', '']]

Comment: I also tried to hard code it sir. But It couldn't do. may be its *

Comment: yeah, last value has some problem sir !

Comment: I corrected it and added a break statement in case the last two values are not Letter and Value as in your case. Should work now. I will delete all comments past the edits